# Using php with an offline html5 app

Tags: php, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have bulit an offline HTML5 application that I have ported to android using cordova. Now the application has some php scripts linked to it that pull dynamic content from my web server to the html5 android app.

A sample of the PHP code is this include in the `index.html`

```
                 <div class="blog-post">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <?php include 'includes/news_index.php';?>

                    </div> <!-- .blog-meta --> 
                 </div> <!-- .blog-post-->
```

`news_index.php` is stored in my online web server. How do I point the url so that the app is able to pull the content from the server to my application?

Comment: i think you should call android functions for loading content from web and adding it by js in your app

Comment: or look at Cordova with PhoneGap. I know a little about them, but i suppose it somehow may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

@nick,
remove any unneeded HTML elements from the content in your PHP script. Make the call with JQuery, and insert with JQuery. It would look like this:

**HTML**
`<div id=content></div>`

**Javascript**
`$.get("http://server/includes/news_index.php", function(data) {
    $( "#content" ).html( data );
});`

Here is the reference: [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

A popular light-weight alternative is [zeptojs](http://zeptojs.com/)

FWIW, you want to remove any unneeded HTML because new HTML engines are not forgiving with this.

Best of Luck.

Comment: I just want to verify (upon my point of view): By using `$.get()`,  the data in `news_index.php` will be returned **even** when it is offline?